# Deleting specific lines in csv files

Tags: python, csv

The csv file looks like below: (with a thousand more lines)

```
step0:  
141  
step1:  
140   
step2:  
4  
step3:  
139  
step4:  
137  
step5:  
136  
15  
step6:  
134  
13  
139  
step7:  
133  
19
```

I am trying to read each line and remove lines (the ones that includes numbers only) that are, say, greater than 27.

Originally, my csv file a string file, so all of the lines are considered strings.

What I have done is the following:

1. first loop through the lines that does not include "step" in them
2. change them into float
3. remove all that are greater than 27

Now I want to save (overwrite) my file after deleting these numbers but I am stuck.
Could someone assist?

```
import csv
f = open('list.csv', 'r')
reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter="\n")
for row in reader:
    for e in row:
        if 'step' not in e:
            d=float(e)                  
            if d>27:
                del(d)
```

Comment: If you remove last value in some step, should that step be removed too?

Comment: is this actually a csv? This seems more like a text file than columns and fields separated by commas

Comment: no @AndrejKesely , not the whole step, just the value

Comment: @RyanSchaefer , yes it is a csv, but it doesn't have to be

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import csv

with open('output.csv', 'w+') as output_file:
    with open('input.csv') as input_file: #change you file name here
        reader = csv.reader(input_file, delimiter = '\n')

        line_index = 0 # debugging 

        for row in reader:
            line_index += 1 
            line = row[0]
            if 'step' in line:
                output_file.write(line)
                output_file.write('\n')
            else:
                try:
                    number = int(line) # you can use float, but then 30 become 30.0 

                    if number <= 27:
                        output_file.write(line)
                        output_file.write('\n')
                except:
                    print("Abnormal data at line %s", str(line_index))
```

I assume that your input file is input.csv. This program writes to new output file. The output is output.csv:

```
step0:
step1:
step2:
4
step3:
step4:
step5:
15
step6:
13
step7:
19
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import csv
with open('list.csv', 'r') as list:
    with open('new_list.csv', 'w') as new_list:
        reader = csv.reader(list, delimiter="\n")
        writer = csv.writer(new_list, delimiter="\n")
        for row in reader:
            if 'step' not in e:
                if float(e) < 27:
                    writer.writerow(e)
            else:
                writer.writerow(e)
```

Essentially you're going to just copy over the rows you want to your new file. If the line is `step`, we write it. If the line is less than 27, we write it. If you'd prefer to just overwrite your file when you're done:

```
import csv
rows_to_keep = []
with open('list.csv', 'r') as list:
    reader = csv.reader(list, delimiter="\n")
    for row in reader:
        if 'step' not in e:
            if float(e) < 27:
                rows_to_keep.append(e)
        else:
            rows_to_keep.append(e)

with open('list.csv', 'w') as new_list:
    writer = csv.writer(list, delimiter="\n")
    writer.write_rows(rows_to_keep)
```

Comment: It looks like it worked, but somehow I'm getting each character in a new line

Comment: Edited to make it work. The difference was iterating over each character instead of each line. Borrowed too much from your original solution

Answer (score 0):

One solution with `re` module:

```
import re

with open('file.txt', 'r') as f_in:
    data = f_in.read()

data = re.sub(r'\b(\d+)\n*', lambda g: '' if int(g.group()) > 27 else g.group(), data)

with open('file_out.txt', 'w') as f_out:
    f_out.write(data)
```

The content of `file_out.txt` will be:

```
step0:
step1:
step2:
4
step3:
step4:
step5:
15
step6:
13
step7:
19
26
```

Comment: Thanks for the assistance, **file_out.txt** was the same as the original file but with the number before the comma (that are less than 27), missing

Comment: @Weees Ups, I got the `>` wrong... Now it should be corrected.